# Python: Retrieving information from list

Tags: python-3.x

Just trying to figure out how to retrieve the hours and rate information in a list to do calculation.

The scenario is that the part-time teacher is paid for each subject they teach; the list of subjects is stored as a list. The amount to be paid to a part-time teacher is calculated according to the formula: amount = hours * rate, for each subject taught.  For example, on the Math subject on the list from the code, the calculation would be 9 (hours) * 54.50 (subject rate) to get the amount paid for the Math subject. I'm just stuck on the def calculate_pay(self) section of the PartTimeTeacher class.

Here's the portion of the code:

========

```
    from typing import List, Any

    class Subject:
        def __init__(self, name: str, hours: float, rate: float) -> None:
            self.name = name
            self.hours = hours
            self.rate = rate
    
    class PartTimeTeacher(Subject):
            def __init__(self, name: str, subject: List[Subject]):
            super().__init__(name)
            self.subject = subject

           def calculate_pay(self): # this is the section that I'm trying to work on
           # formula is to get the amount = hours * rate for each subject taught from the subjects list under def main()
                                            

    def main():
        teachers: List[Teacher] = []

       subjects = [
       Subject('Math', 9, 54.5),
       Subject('Science', 5, 62.5),
       Subject('English', 3.5, 40.93)]
```

====

Thank you,

Rogue

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know which one do you prefer. However, you must adjust your inerhitance. It won´t work that way.

#### First approach:

```py
from typing import List


class Subject:
    def __init__(self, name: str, hours: float, rate: float) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.hours = hours
        self.rate = rate


class PartTimeTeacher(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, subject: List[Subject]):
        self.name = name
        self.subject = subject

    def calculate_pay(self):  # this is the section that I'm trying to work on
        currency = dict()
        for ele in self.subject:
            currency[ele.name] = ele.rate * ele.hours
        return {self.name: currency}


def main():
    subjects = [
        Subject('Math', 9, 54.5),
        Subject('Science', 5, 62.5),
        Subject('English', 3.5, 40.93)]

    ptt = PartTimeTeacher('mister_x', subjects)
    print(ptt.calculate_pay())


main()
```

#### Second approach:

```
from typing import List


class Subject:
    def __init__(self, name: str, hours: float, rate: float) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.hours = hours
        self.rate = rate
        self.amount = hours * rate


class PartTimeTeacher(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, subject: List[Subject]):
        self.name = name
        self.subject = [Subject(ele.name, ele.hours, ele.rate) for ele in subject]

    def calculate_pay(self):  # this is the section that I'm trying to work on
        return {self.name: [vars(ele) for ele in self.subject]}


def main():
    subjects = [
        Subject('Math', 9, 54.5),
        Subject('Science', 5, 62.5),
        Subject('English', 3.5, 40.93)]

    ptt = PartTimeTeacher('mister_x', subjects)
    print(ptt.calculate_pay())


main()
```

I hope it´s what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Klim, by the way, just want to clarify, what does ele means on the code you've added?

Comment: @Rogue. For me, it is a short version of `element`. You can use any identifier. `ele` represents a current element or state of the loop. [python loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp). If you want, you can name it `item` instead of `element`.